# Fill below certain threshold

Tags: plotting

How can I insert Fill in the plot below, such that only the area below 0.5 and below the line is filled?

```
Plot[-x + 1, {x, 0, 1}]
```

**EDIT:** I was hoping the solution to this simpler question would also work for my real problem, which involves the following data, but this is not the case:

How can I implement you solution on this data?

Using Michael's solution combined with comments by void life

```
Plot[{data  , Min[1/2, #] & data }, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic,None}, Filling -> {1 -> 0, 2 -> {{1}, White}}]
```

I get:

[image]

```
{0.744318, 0.60038, 0.539471, 0.5542, 0.592916, 0.613237, 0.673014, 0.687572, 0.658548, 0.69416, 0.65248, 0.653574, 0.596889, 0.577856, 0.592349, 0.505633, 0.51403, 0.520655, 0.492696, 0.459513, 0.463524, 0.463181, 0.415386, 0.422303, 0.422072, 0.406222, 0.40379, 0.389445, 0.375038, 0.349756, 0.332508, 0.323173, 0.308245, 0.290745, 0.285053, 0.275322, 0.268835, 0.25514, 0.25281, 0.254935, 0.250978, 0.251613, 0.25431, 0.251915, 0.252345, 0.253374, 0.253928, 0.248666, 0.25169, 0.253212, 0.257687, 0.257374, 0.256379, 0.262966, 0.263945, 0.268633, 0.270197, 0.273909, 0.274298, 0.275465, 0.274321, 0.273316}
```

[image]

Comment: `Plot[{-x + 1, Min[1/2, -x + 1]}, {x, 0, 1},   PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None}, Filling -> {2 -> 0}]`?

Comment: I see the trick.

Comment: What is the problem with using Michael's method with your data? Plot your data and `Min[1/2,#]& data` in the same way as the example.

Comment: @void life See my latest edit

Comment: Sorry I meant `Min[1/2, #]& /@ data`. You need to actually `Map` the values of data to the function. Secondly, Plot takes a function not just a bunch of data points. You need to use `ListLinePlot` or similar or create a function that will return values from your data. E.g `ListLinePlot[{data, Min[1/2, #] & /@ data}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> 0, 2 -> {{1}, White}}]` will give you what you are after

Answer (score 3):

Possibly also this:

```
Plot[{-x + 1, Min[1/2, -x + 1]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> 0, 2 -> {{1}, White}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited my question. I set out to provide a simple example, but it turns out my real problem may not be solved so easily using your otherwise instructive example.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {0.744318, 0.60038, 0.539471, 0.5542, 0.592916, 0.613237, 
   0.673014, 0.687572, 0.658548, 0.69416, 0.65248, 0.653574, 0.596889,
    0.577856, 0.592349, 0.505633, 0.51403, 0.520655, 0.492696, 
   0.459513, 0.463524, 0.463181, 0.415386, 0.422303, 0.422072, 
   0.406222, 0.40379, 0.389445, 0.375038, 0.349756, 0.332508, 
   0.323173, 0.308245, 0.290745, 0.285053, 0.275322, 0.268835, 
   0.25514, 0.25281, 0.254935, 0.250978, 0.251613, 0.25431, 0.251915, 
   0.252345, 0.253374, 0.253928, 0.248666, 0.25169, 0.253212, 
   0.257687, 0.257374, 0.256379, 0.262966, 0.263945, 0.268633, 
   0.270197, 0.273909, 0.274298, 0.275465, 0.274321, 0.273316};

threshold = 0.5;

Show[Plot[data, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None}], 
 Plot[threshold, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Min@data]]
```

[image]

Or

```
Show[Plot[data, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, None}, 
  PlotRange -> {0.2, 0.8}], 
 Plot[threshold, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> 0.2]]
```

[image]